# Codeigniter disabling browser page caching for admin panel

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, caching

I am developing a website with codeigniter 3.1.5 HMVC and now I am writing the admin panel.

I designed log in screen and dashboard panel. I can login and logout successfully, there is no problem in sessions etc.

But my problem is , my browser (Chrome) is caching my dashboard page and after the logout, when I click to 'Go Back' button on my browser I can see the cached dashboard page but I want to disable it. (When I refresh the page, it is redirecting me to login panel)

## How I understood that the problem is with browser?

I am developing the site in my local wamp server. After I logout, I stopped the wamp server and click to Go Back button and browser load the page (But it should't load so it is coming from browser's cache)

I tried these codes in my controllers' every location (in constructor or after logout etc) but it didn't solve the problem.

```
    $this->output->set_header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
    $this->output->set_header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    $this->output->set_header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
    $this->output->set_header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()).' GMT');
    $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    $this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

How can I fix this issue?
Thanks, best regards.

Comment: Solution would be [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Comment: Ok,Could you give me some example code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. Edit your question and post current code. Meaning controller code where is login/logout logic at least.

Comment: @Tpojka Thank you for your answer. I tried your suggestion and now it works for me. While applying Post/Redirect/Get, I used this pattern : [link](https://www.injavawetrust.com/jsf-08-page-forward-page-redirect-postredirectget/). Thank you so much :)

Comment: Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but use the given header Cache-Control code with max-age=0

```
$this->output->set_header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
$this->output->set_header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
$this->output->set_header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
$this->output->set_header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()).' GMT');
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0");
$this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where should I locate this line?

Comment: Check now. Edited the answer for you. And let me know if it worked or not.

Comment: Nope. I think I should try @Tpojka 's method. Thanks.